# font awesome in gojs

Tags: font-awesome, gojs

In gojs, you can't use CSS to display the font-awesome icon as it's using a canvas.  So I specify the font and use the Unicode value to display the icon.   it works for one icon but not another..  both are free icons.

This shows fa-regular fa-file-lines

```
            $(go.TextBlock, {
            font: "12px 'Font Awesome 6 Free'",
            text: '\uf15c',
```

This should show  fa-solid fa-gear

```
        $(go.TextBlock, {
            font: "12px 'Font Awesome 6 Free'",
            text: '\uf013',
```

But, I suspect it's trying to show the fa-regular version, which is in the Pro pack.  any idea how I can get it to show the fa-solid one ?